# Angular custom structural directive fails to rebuild ViewContainer if template contains *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I have an issue with ViewContainers and Structural Directives.

I have a custom structural directive = eg “permissionAccess".

It selects data from my **NGRX store** and looks for matching permissions.
If no permission it clears the ViewContainer. If it has permission it Rebuilds the **ViewContainer** using the injected **TemplateRef**.
(This all works fine - I have tested with Dom elements, Components, Views)

But… it fails to rebuild the ViewContainer if any of the Dom contains **"ngIf"** directives.

Anyone know why this would happen?? I have no idea!

It even fails with the `*ngIf=“true”`

Template Example Works:

```
<div *cwbPermission=“'ADMIN'">
        <p>test container</p>
        <div>
          <p>Nested container1</p>
          <div>
            <p>Nested container2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Template Example Fails:

```
<div *cwbPermission=“'ADMIN'">
        <p>test container</p>
        <div *ngIf=“true">
          <p>Nested container1</p>
          <div>
            <p>Nested container2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Can anyone explain this to me?? I have no idea!

Comment: I have tried https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-structural-directive-fails-to-rebuild-viewcontai?file=src/app/cwb-permission.directive.ts it's working fine.

Comment: Ok thanks @chellappan.  Guess I will need to create a stackblitz to show the issue properly then.  I am using a subscription to NGRX Store, a hardcoded list, and some more conditional logic that could be affecting the rebuild in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am not sure if this the best approach to this issue but looks like it is working for me.
I added a changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after creating the template in the view container and the UI now updates as I expect.
Not seen any issues so far.

```
 /**
  * Creates the template content
  */
  showContent(): void {
    this.viewContainer.remove();
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context, 0);
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }
```